# Saving user generated values

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

Is it a good idea to save user generated values in a .xml file in the res values folder?
The values look like "Aircraft", "Type", "Note" in one row. Is it even possible to save Values there while runtime and is it possible to save there a multi-part value?

I just want to know, what's the most recommended way to save a three part value, to show it in a Table (table layout).

Comment: I've only been checking out Android for 4 hours and I've already seen the topic of "User Preferences".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all android .apk file is read only so you can't store values in `/res` directory at runtime..**

You an store these values in `Shared Preferences`, Xml file and then it in `internal storage` or `sdcard` and in `SQLite database`..

Now you have a multi-part values, and you want to display it as a table layout format, So I think **SQLite database is useful for it**..

Now choice is yours..

Comment: okay thanks, didnt know, that the .apk file is read only, because i saw some tuts which discribe how to add f.eg. table rows while runtime to a table layout.

Comment: @mkay - In that tutorials, they add rows runtime by programatically, not in xml file..

Answer (score 0):

If your amount of data is small, you can consider using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).
Else, the prefered way to store persistent data is using a SQLite database I think.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't save values to res folder at run time.** you can store those data in Shared Preference or in SQLite database or